# Automated re-identification of free-text medical records

Tags: nlp, health

I am looking for a program that can perform automated re-identification of de-identified free-text medical records. The de-identification applied the Health Insurance Portability and Accountability Act (HIPAA) rules (US regulations), i.e. the following information were removed from the text:

```
(i) Names of patients and family members
(ii) Addresses and their components
(iii) Dates (month and day parts, unless the inclusion of the year part identities an individual to be older than 90 years old)
(iv) Explicit mention of ages over 89 years old
(v) Telephone and fax numbers
(vi) Social Security numbers
(vii) Medical record numbers
(viii) Health plan beneficiary numbers
(ix) Account numbers
(x) Certificate or license numbers
(xi) Vehicle identifiers and serial numbers
(xii) Device identifers and serial numbers
(xiii) Electronic mail addresses
(xiv) Web universal resource locators (URLs)
(xv) Internet protocol (IP) addresses
(xvi) Biometric identifiers
(xvii) Full face photographic images
(xviii) Employers
(xix) Any other unique identifying number, characteristic or code
```

Example:

> Patient ID: [ID]
>
> [NAME] is a [AGE]-year-old woman with a history of diabetes. She
> arrived at [HOSPITAL] on [DATE] complaining of abdominal pain. Dr.
> [PHYSICIAN] diagnosed her with appendicitis and admitted her at 10 PM.

would be converted into:

> Patient ID: ID586
>
> Sandy Parkinson is a 34-year-old woman with a history of diabetes. She arrived at Mercy Hospital on July 10 complaining of abdominal pain. Dr. Myron Prendergast diagnosed her with appendicitis and admitted her at 10 PM.

where the identification is random (i.e., one does not try to find out what was the actual identifiable data, but instead one only tries to comes up with plausible data, aka. suitable replacements).
I am aware the [MITRE Identification Scrubber Toolkit (MIST)](http://mist-deid.sourceforge.net/) can do it, but I'm looking for an alternative.

Any license, price, and OS is fine.

Ideally, it should be able to clever re-identified several notes pertaining to the same patient (e.g., the name of the patient would be the same across those notes).